# How to wait for Swift's URLSession to finish before running again?

Tags: swift, firebase, nsurlsession, google-books

Probably a stupid question, but I'm a beginner at this.

The below code is supposed to get book information from Google Books from a keyword search. It then goes through the results and checks if I have a matching ISBN in a Firebase database. It works, but currently can only search 40 books as that's the Google Books API maximum per search.

Fortunately, I can specify where to start the index and get the next 40 books to search as well. Unfortunately, I've been trying for hours to understand how the URLSession works. All the methods I've tried have shown me that the code after the URLSession block doesn't necessarily wait for the session to complete. So if I check if I've found any matches afterward, it might not even be done searching.

I suspect the answer is in completion handling, but my attempts so far have been unsuccessful. Below is my code with a URL setup to take various starting index values.

```
var startingIndex = 0

        //encode keyword(s) to be appended to URL
        let query = query.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
        let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=\(query)&&maxResults=40&startIndex=\(startingIndex)"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }else{

                let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]

                if let items = json["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    //for each result make a book and add title
                    for item in items {
                        if let volumeInfo = item["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            let book = Book()
                            //default values
                            book.isbn13 = "isbn13"
                            book.isbn10 = "isbn10"
                            book.title = volumeInfo["title"] as? String

                            //putting all authors into one string
                            if let temp = volumeInfo["authors"] as? [String] {
                                var authors = ""
                                for i in 0..<temp.count {
                                    authors = authors + temp[i]
                                }
                                book.author = authors
                            }

                            if let imageLinks = volumeInfo["imageLinks"] as? [String: String] {
                                book.imageURL = imageLinks["thumbnail"]
                            }

                            //assign isbns
                            if let isbns = volumeInfo["industryIdentifiers"] as? [[String: String]] {

                                for i in 0..<isbns.count {

                                    let firstIsbn = isbns[i]
                                    if firstIsbn["type"] == "ISBN_10" {
                                        book.isbn10 = firstIsbn["identifier"]
                                    }else{
                                        book.isbn13 = firstIsbn["identifier"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            //adding book to an array of books
                            myDatabase.child("listings").child(book.isbn13!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                if snapshot.exists() {
                                    if listings.contains(book) == false{
                                        listings.append(book)
                                    }
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
                                }
                            })
                            myDatabase.child("listings").child(book.isbn10!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                if snapshot.exists() {
                                    if listings.contains(book) == false{
                                        listings.append(book)
                                    }
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }.resume()
```

Below is my revised code:

```
 func searchForSale(query: String, startingIndex: Int) {

        directionsTextLabel.isHidden = true
        tableView.isHidden = false
        listings.removeAll()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
        SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Searching")

        //clear previous caches of textbook images
        cache.clearMemoryCache()
        cache.clearDiskCache()
        cache.cleanExpiredDiskCache()


        let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=\(query)&&maxResults=40&startIndex=\(startingIndex)"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }else{

                var needToContinueSearch = true

                let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]

                if json["error"] == nil {

                    let totalItems = json["totalItems"] as? Int
                    if totalItems == 0 {
                        SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "No matches found")
                        return
                    }

                    if let items = json["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                        //for each result make a book and add title
                        for item in items {

                            if let volumeInfo = item["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

                                let book = Book()
                                //default values
                                book.isbn13 = "isbn13"
                                book.isbn10 = "isbn10"
                                book.title = volumeInfo["title"] as? String

                                //putting all authors into one string
                                if let temp = volumeInfo["authors"] as? [String] {
                                    var authors = ""
                                    for i in 0..<temp.count {
                                        authors = authors + temp[i]
                                    }
                                    book.author = authors
                                }

                                if let imageLinks = volumeInfo["imageLinks"] as? [String: String] {
                                    book.imageURL = imageLinks["thumbnail"]
                                }

                                //assign isbns
                                if let isbns = volumeInfo["industryIdentifiers"] as? [[String: String]] {

                                    for i in 0..<isbns.count {

                                        let firstIsbn = isbns[i]
                                        //checks if isbns have invalid characters
                                        let isImproperlyFormatted = firstIsbn["identifier"]!.contains {".$#[]/".contains($0)}

                                        if isImproperlyFormatted == false {
                                            if firstIsbn["type"] == "ISBN_10" {
                                                book.isbn10 = firstIsbn["identifier"]
                                            }else{
                                                book.isbn13 = firstIsbn["identifier"]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                //adding book to an array of books
                                myDatabase.child("listings").child(book.isbn13!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                    if snapshot.exists() {
                                        if listings.contains(book) == false{
                                            listings.append(book)
                                            needToContinueSearch = false
                                        }
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
                                    }
                                })
                                myDatabase.child("listings").child(book.isbn10!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                    if snapshot.exists() {
                                        if listings.contains(book) == false{
                                            listings.append(book)
                                            needToContinueSearch = false
                                        }
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
                                        return
                                    }
                                    if startingIndex < 500 {
                                        if needToContinueSearch {
                                            let nextIndex = startingIndex + 40
                                            self.searchForSale(query: query, startingIndex: nextIndex)
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    return
                }
            }

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }.resume()

        //hide keyboard
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: A few things that are unclear but unrelated to the question. In the code section where the isbn's are iterated over, if there are more than one ISBN_10, the prior one is overwritten. If not, the isbn13 is overwritten by the prior one. Not sure why  as we don't know what isbs contains in the first place. The Firebase closures may be an issue as the second one could complete before the first - more importantly is the explicitly unwrapped optionals *book.isbn13!* could be nil and crash. Lastly, Firebase closures run their UI updates on the main thread to DispatchQueue is not necessary.

Comment: And your question; The URLSession is asynchronous and from the docs *By calling a completion handler block when a transfer finishes successfully or with an error.* So that means the code in the completion handler (closure) will only be called when the URL session has completed the transfer and contains data. Can you clarify the question as to what the specific issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your completion handler if any results have been returned you end with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
```

to trigger reloading of your table with the updated information. At this same point is where you could determine of there may be more results and initiate the next asynchronous URL task. In outline your code might be:

```
let needToContinueSearch : Bool = ...;

DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }

if needToContinueSearch
{  // call routine it initiate next async URL task
}
```

*(If there is any reason to start the task from the main thread the `if` would be in the block.)*

By not initiating the next search until after you've processed the results of the first you avoid having to deal with any issues of a subsequent callback trying to update your data at the same time as a previous one.

However if you find delaying the second search in this way is too slow you can investigate ways to overlap the operations, e.g. you might have the callback just pass the processing of the results to an async task on a serial queue (so that only one set of results is being processed at once) and initiate the next async URL task.

HTH

Comment: Thenk you, this really helped! I'm still a bit confused though and was wondering if you would be willing to take another look at my revised code which I've added above. It seems to work and searches beyond the usual 40, but I don't know where I should reset the my bool "needToContinueSearch" so that I can run a separate search afterward.

Comment: You have promoted `needToContinueSearch` to be an instance variable, it is only used *within* `searchForSale` and so should only be declared within it; and it is this promotion which is causing you to need to reset it. Just declare and use the variable within the function.

Comment: Sorry to ask yet again, but I'm still not sure I understand this completion handler. I've again edited my code above, but it searches hundreds of times and slowly increments the startingIndex whether or not it triggered the needToContinueSearch bool.

Can you verify that the code I want to run after the networking is done should be put right after this "(data, response, error) in" ?

Comment: You initialise your `needToContinueSearch` to `true` so the default for your design is to continue the search. If your code is continuing the search when it shouldn't then your logic for setting the variable `false` is incorrect. You need to trace your logic, using breakpoints might help, and determine the flow of your code. You might find it easier, as in the answer above, to declare and set `needToContinueSearch` in one operation based on the result of a boolean expression, i.e. do not declare and initialise it one way and then based on tests set it the other way. HTH

Comment: I've been trying so many ways to track the logic, but it just isn't consistent. Everything I do while looping through my items array remains unchanged afterwards. If I find a match and append it to "listings" it's still an empty array outside of the loop. Similarly, if I set my bool to false when I find a match, it goes right back to true afterwards.

Comment: It sounds like you may have issues with asynchronicity or variable copying or capture with closures; all can manifest as modified values apparently resetting to previous values. Reading up on those topics, including looking at SO Q&A in these areas, should help you figure it. If you can produce a small example which doesn't work as you expect you can ask a new question, at the moment this question has become too unfocused and there's too little detail for people to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a bool variable as isLoading and if that function is loading dont trigger urlsession. hope below sample will help you.

```
var isLoading : Bool = false

func loadMore(with pageCount: Int){
    if isLoading { return }
    isLoading = true
    // call the network
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "xxxxx")!) { (data, response, error) in

        // after updating the data set isloding to false again
        // do the api logic here
        // 
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // self.items = downloadedItems 
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.isLoading = false
        }

    }.resume()

}
```